# How setup SSL on Azure with Java/Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, azure

we are using worker roles to host java apps that are essentially Tompact and App code within an azure package.

We want to be able to setup SSL without having to bake the certs into the app package in a similar way to the .Net side, where you can refer to certs in the certificate store.

How can this be achieved?

I have read this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2010/11/07/adding-ssl-https-security-with-tomcat-java-solution-in-windows-azure.aspx which states we need to create a keystore.bin file from the cert and include it in the package.

The problem is, I dont want to bake the certs into the package for ease of management when rolling out code to multiple environments with different certs etc, and also from a management point of view around cert expiry etc.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

The key is how do you want to bring the certificate in the Azure VM to be configured and and used by Tomcat. Another key question is that Tomcat/Java does not use standard Windows CertStore for certificate instead it uses keystore (extended part of your Java runtime) so if you are not using key store configuration in Windows Azure Package then you would need to create on fly during Windows Azure VM configuration.

While others may have different idea, I can propose the following solution:

1. You need Tomcat Installation done at this point do either you can pack tomcat with Azure 
   Package or you would need to download and install Tomcat through Startup task
2. Drop the certificate files on Windows Azure Storage (or some other location on internet)
3. Create a start up task to download certs either from Windows Azure Storage or your download location
4. After the certificate is downloaded to local machine, run the same command in Azure VM within startup task to build the key store and be sure to create keystore where your tomcat is going to look it.
5. This way when the Tomcat starts it knows where to look for key store and configure the endpoint properly.

There is another way is to put together whole Tomcat setup along with keystore etc at Windows Azure Storage and download through Startup task and set it up in the Azure VM. I have described this process in my this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/08/17/full-startup-task-based-tomcat-java-worker-role-application-for-windows-azure.aspx) along with sample source.

In both of above ways whenever you would want to change the Tomcat/certificate, just update the package at your download location and then re-image/Restart the Azure VM and you will have updated VM with new code and you really don't need tore-create Windows Azure Package.

Comment: thanks avkash. I have already read your blog. The issue is we are using a third party to write the app and hand over the package. We as a company dont want to have to pay the dev house to rebuild the package for simple opps tasks such as spin up a new env with different certificates, or change expired certificates. We want to  be self sufficient. Is there a way to script the pulling of the cert from the cert store into the VM, and then create a script to create the keystore bin?

Comment: also how safe is the cert on blob storage compared to it living in the cert store in the platform?

Comment: When a blob (any thing) is on Blob store it is accessible to anyone one the have access to key. When a cert is in the VM, it is accessible to anyone who has access to your VM. So the "safety" of any content is very subjective aspect and can not be explained very clearly.